# Derivative of Adjugate Matrix, $\frac{d^i}{dx^i}\operatorname {Adj}(x \mathbf I - \mathbf A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators, cayley-hamilton

Let $\mathbf A$ denote an $n \times n$ matrix with $r=\operatorname{rank}\mathbf A$ and define
$$ \mathbf B_i(x) \equiv \frac{d^i}{dx^i}\operatorname {Adj}(x \mathbf I - \mathbf A). $$
**Conjecture:**

> If $n - r \ge 2$, then 
>   $$ \mathbf B_i(0)= \mathbf 0, \quad \text{for all } i \in \{0,...,n-r-2\}.  $$

Comment: @Semiclassical It is a scalar. $d^i/dx^i$ means the $i$-th order derivative with respect to $x$.

Comment: @Semiclassical You can consider $\text{Adj}(xI-A)$ as a matrix of functions of $x$ and differentiate it element by element.

Comment: @mzp That makes a lot more sense, thanks. In essence, then, you want to show that the Taylor series at x=0 for Adj(xI-A) vanishes to at least order $n-r-2$.

Comment: The formula shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Characteristic_polynomial) on Wikipedia's page for the adjugate matrix seems like it could be handy.

Comment: @Semiclassical I tried to go that route, and then use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, but couldn't get it to work, which is just a statement about my own abilities :)

Comment: I actually think it might be easier to argue something like: if $r\le n-2$, then $\operatorname*{Adj}(\mathbf{A})=\mathbf{0}$, therefore, each element of the matrix $\operatorname*{Adj}(x\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{A})$ is a polynomial in $x$ with at least $n-r-1$ zero roots, which implies that there exists a polynomial matrix $\mathbf{C}(x)$ such that
$\operatorname{Adj}(x \mathbf I - \mathbf A)=x^{n-r-1}\mathbf{C}(x)$. But I haven't been able to formalize this.